# Select new not data binding rad GridView

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview

My select new statement get values from two different tables 
but it does not data bind in the grid view please help.

```
var search = (from u in db.Users
              join s in db.Sites on u.SiteID equals s.SiteID
              where u.FirstName.Contains(tbSearch.Text.Trim())
              select new 
              {
                  u.FirstName,
                  u.LastName,
                  u.Username,
                  u.Password,
                  s.SiteName,
                  u.Active
              });

if (search != null)
{

    rgUsers.DataSource = search;
    rgUsers.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`search` is a query definition. It's not a result of query execution. So, checking if `search != null` just verifies that query was assigned to variable `search`. It does not verify that some data would be returned when query gets executed. E.g. `if (search.Any())` executes query and verifies that something was returned. But each invocation of query will be separate database query (which is performance hit). So, if you want to assign data only if result is not empty, you should execute query, save its results to in-memory list and then check if list is not empty:

```
var userSites = search.ToList(); // single database query here
if (userSites.Any()) // in-memory check without database query
{
    rgUsers.DataSource = userSites;
    rgUsers.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks fo the quick response.

Comment: unfortunatley it still displays nothing in the grid view.

Comment: @WhiteSpider try to turn on AutoGenerateColumns for grid, and make sure query result is not empty

Comment: no doesnt work, if change my select statement to "select u;" then it populates the gridview but without the s.sitename

Comment: @WhiteSpider make sure you have data returned from database

Comment: yes i have debugged it and usersites holds values. Why would it populate when i use "select u;" but not with "select new {...}"

Comment: any other suggestions ?